# Can't play League of Legends with PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, 17.04

I installed PlayOnLinux in Ubuntu 17.04 and installed League of Legends, but when I try to open the League of Legends launcher, bugsplat appears from wine icon every 3 or 4 seconds, and even if I close it it appears again. I have to close League of Legends from the PlayOnLinux client. If somebody plays LoL on Linux please tell me how it is possible to use Linux and Windows in the same laptop, Windows for games, Linux for common use? Or is better using VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes, dual boot should be possible and it's the best option for games.

Answer (score 0):

In POL select wine 2.8staging and win vista. If LoL is updated to the new client add a launch icon for it. If it doesn't work like this, you may have to install extra libraries, Google may tell you which. If you want more help or a step by step guide ask Google or go to [reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/)